# Problème HQL JAVA Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, request, hql

I have 2 classes(Entity)  : "Programme" and  "Livre"

in my Livre hbm.xml i Have :

```
* boolean type

* <many-to-one
            name="programme"
            column="idprogramme"
            class="Programme"
        />
```

```
In my code JAVA
```

```
     public List<Programme> getProgrammesLivres() {
            final String requete = "from Programme as p , livre as l where p.id = l.idprogramme and l.type=true ";
            return (List<Programme>) getHibernateTemplate().find(requete);
        }
```

but it doesn't work, do I have a problem with my request or mycode java?
Thnqs

Comment: What is the problem or error?

Comment: I have no results instead of displaying the reads of programs that have a book type = true